# jqGrid search delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I use jqGrid's filter toolbar with option searchOnEnter: false. And it sends requests immediately after I entered some text in field. In my application it may be better to wait while user entered text he wanted and search it when he stops typing. So, is in jqGrid posibility to add delay before request will be sent to server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's correct question, but jqGrid has no option to specify the timeout before applying of automatically searching. It is always 500 ms.

If you examine the source code of `filterToolbar` you will find [the following lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.custom.js#L446-463) which uses the `searchOnEnter` option.

```js
$("input",thd).keydown(function(e){
    var key = e.which;
    switch (key) {
        case 13:
            return false;
        case 9 :
        case 16:
        case 37:
        case 38:
        case 39:
        case 40:
        case 27:
            break;
        default :
            if(timeoutHnd) { clearTimeout(timeoutHnd); }
            timeoutHnd = setTimeout(function(){triggerToolbar();},500);
    }
});
```

So you can use practically the same code together with default `searchOnEnter: false` option and implement the call of `triggerToolbar` manually after the timeout which you need. For example the following fragmant of the code start searching after 3 sec (3000 ms) timeout after the typing in the searching toolbar:

```js
var timeoutHnd, k = $.ui.keyCode,
    toSkip = [k.TAB, k.SHIFT, k.ALT, k.ESCAPE, k.LEFT, k.UP, k.RIGHT, k.DOWN, k.HOME, k.END, k.INSERT];
$grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar", {defaultSearch: "cn"});
$grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid-view")
    .find(".ui-jqgrid-hdiv .ui-search-toolbar input[type=text]")
    .keydown(function (e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if (key === k.ENTER) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($.inArray(key, toSkip) < 0) {
            if (timeoutHnd) {
                clearTimeout(timeoutHnd);
                timeoutHnd = 0;
            }
            timeoutHnd = setTimeout(function () {
                $grid[0].triggerToolbar();
                timeoutHnd = 0;
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
```

[Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/toolbarsearchwithtimeout.htm) is the corresponding demo:

[image]

**UPDATED:** [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid supports `autosearchDelay` option  (default value is 500) of `filterToolbar` which can be used in combination with `autosearch: true` (it's default) and `searchOnEnter: false`. Thus the trick described above is not required. One can just use

```
$grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
    searchOnEnter: false,
    autosearchDelay: 3000 // 3 sec
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the data is fetched from server. I tried your code, and it doesn't work if using server-side data. Nevertheless, if the data is local (like in your example), this works just fine. Got any ideas how to change the delay when the data is fetched remotely?

Comment: @user2435860: First of all: what exactly "doesn't work". Seconds: what you did exactly and which version and fork of jqGrid you used? [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) is the fork which I develop. It has `autosearchDelay` option of `filterToolbar`, which can be used in combination with `autosearch: true`. Thus you can use `{ autosearch: true, autosearchDelay: 3000 }` as the option of `filterToolbar`. It works for any `datatype`.

Comment: hello, I am using the jqgrid version 4.6. I am loading data and manipulate it using server-side processing, and added a filter option. The problem is that I cannot change the delay from the setTimeout like you did. It doesn't work with data that comes from a server. My problem is that I work with a lot of data, and 500ms is not enough as a delay, because afterwards the jqgrid is locked until the new filtered data is fetched, which locks my web app. I am trying to find a way to stop the triggerToolbar(), but unsuccessful until now. Do you have a recommendation for me?

Comment: @user2435860: I recommend you to upgrade to free jqGrid 4.12.1. You can test it by changing the URL to URLs from CDN described on [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). It's available from the most well-known repositories: npm, bower, NuGet, WebJars, see [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md). Only if you can't upgrade now you should verify that you don't use `searchOnEnter: false` and to implement `keydown` in your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are some constraints that keep me from changing the library. I am forced to use this version :( do you know any way of stopping the triggering when I press on a key? So I can implement my own timeout

Comment: @user2435860: Sorry, but I wrote you previously: **verify that you don't use `searchOnEnter: false`**.

Comment: @user2435860: Then you did some error. It has no sense to write me that you can't find the error in your code. If you want that I help you then you should provide the demo, which I can debug. Moreover I wrote you already that the statement "it does not work" gives practically no information. **What** is not work? Is the request will be send before the end of expected timeout? Is no request to the server will be send after the timeout, ...

Comment: Ok, I double checked and as it seems, there was a duplicate of "searchOnEnter: false" in the code, in another js file. Now it works, Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @user2435860: You are welcome! The solved problem is a good problem.